# Generics Sub List

Tags: c#, generics, c#-2.0

Check the code.

```
class DynamicObj : BaseObj {}
class BaseObj {}

class clientCode 
{
   List<DynamicObj> GetFilteredObjs(List<BaseObj> baseList) 
   {
        // I want to return the sublist of baseList which only have DynamicObj.
        List<DynamicObj> dList = baseList.FindAll(
                                          delegate(BaseObj bo){        // Del1
                                          return bo is DynamicObj;
                                          }).ConvertAll<DynamicObj>(
                                             delegate(BaseObj bo){     // Del2 
                                             return bo as DynamicObj;
                                             });   

   }
}
```

Now it might be a silly question, But my code will have to loop objects 2 times,once for Del1 loop and once for Del2 loop.

Is there any straight way? C# 2.0 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
IEnumerable<DynamicObj> GetDynamicObjects(IEnumerable<BaseObj> baseList)
{
    foreach(BaseObj baseObj in baseList)
        if(baseObj is DynamicObj)
            yield return (DynamicObj)baseObj;
}

List<DynamicObj> dynamicList = new List<DynamicObj>(GetDynamicObjects(...));
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use an iterator block:

```
public IEnumerable<TTarget> FilteredCast<TSource,TTarget>
    (IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    where TSource : class
    where TTarget : class, TSource
{
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        TTarget converted = element as TTarget;
        if (converted != null)
        {
            yield return converted;
        }
    }
}
```

(This is basically the `Enumerable.OfType` method in LINQ to Objects, btw. I've restricted it to reference types for convenience, but it's still generic so you can reuse it more easily.)

Then just write:

```
List<DynamicObj> GetFilteredObjs(List<BaseObj> baseList) 
{
    return new List<DynamicObj>(FilteredCast<BaseObj,DynamicObj>(baseList);
}
```

Note that this won't return nulls. If you want nulls to be included, you'd need to cater for that explicitly.